# Sonarqube with maven does not find artifact

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am trying to analyse my project with **sonarqube**.

I configure my project following the website, but the error below is shown when I run

`mvn sonar:sonar`

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'org.codehaus.
mojo:sonar-maven-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifac
t from any repository

  org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Why is it looking for **2.0-SNAPSHOT** ?

Comment: look for plugin version effective applied to your pom.xml by `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: what do I look for after running this command?

Comment: plugin declaration what version it has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added this plugin to my pom.xml and it worked.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</plugin>
```